# Match all the characters which are not in a particular set

Tags: regex, abap

Regular expression that matches based on the below:

1. Regex should match all the characters in the string which are not
   in `(a-zA-Z0-9/-?:().,'+{}\S)` i.e. 
   `a-z,A-Z,0-9,/,-,?,,,:,(,),.,',+,{,},\S`
2. String can have spaces but the string should not be an empty one.

MATCH should be as below:

- String equals `Regex test && 123456789 $$`  in the above regex it
  should find/replace the characters `&` and `$`

I have tried the below and is not working :

```
(?=.[a-zA-Z0-9/-?:().,'+{}\s])
```

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: add a ^sign to invert the character set: [^a-zA-Z0-9/-?:().,`+{}\s]

Comment: 1) if you're using `-` in `[ ]` pattern, you have to put it on the border, ie `[a-z-]` (it's a special character). 2) Your regex is a lookahead that will validate strings composed of one character (any character, that's the `.`) followed by one of the character you DON'T want (and it won't work because of the `-` thing). Also it won't match anything as lookahead have zero-width. 3) @Ashalynd gave you the answer to how to match what you want (`[^a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+{}\s-]+`) 4) What do you want to do? Replace these characters? With what?

Comment: @Robin presumably nothing. It looks like the goal is to remove 'illegal' characters from input strings.

Comment: The regex engine in ABAP has some limitations, but unless your specific example highlights any of them, I don't think your question should be tagged with ABAP.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you take a step back and explain what you are trying to do, maybe with a more concrete example. Perhaps there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This ABAP regular expression works for me in ABAP using your example:

```
[^[:alnum:]/\-?:().,'+{}[:space:]]+
```

`^` is for negating the sets of characters. Read the ABAP documentation for more information : [Negation of a Self-Defined Set for Single Characters](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_syntax_signs.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SYNTAX_SIGNS_5)

I'm using `[:alnum:]` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9` since it has better internationalization matching on non-latin words. Read the ABAP documentation for more information: [Character Classes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_syntax_signs.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SYNTAX_SIGNS_7)

Note: ABAP 7.53 regular expressions use the ["Version 1.31 of the Boost.Regex Library"](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenregular_expressions.htm).